# How to hide a part of a CSS borderline nicely

Tags: html, css

i'm doing a web app for iPhone, i'm having some troubles with borders.
To simplify things i have a background image for body, a box with rounded corners which have some elements inside and a title, and that's where problems begins as i want my title to be on the top border of my box without having the borderline behind it.

Here is a screenshot :
  [image: problematic box]
I can't see any solutions to render it properly, some of you have any guess ?
It would be much appreciated

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: if the line is removed, what should go in its place? Presumably you want one of the two background images to fill in the gap, but which one? And will it look any better than having the border line there?

Comment: I once had such problem and ended up drawing the border "manually" using `div` elements with height of 1 pixel, proper background color which is the border color and dynamic width, using client side scripting. If you want I'll dig that code up as last resort for you.

Comment: @Shadow: That sounds pretty horrible.

Comment: @You fair enough, like I said: last resort. Never said it's ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather, it looks like you should be using the `fieldset` element (as you are "grouping" form elements together), which conveniently also looks the way you want it to:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Promoter</legend>
    <select>
        <option>Choose a promoter</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Styling is simple. Align the `legend` text and style the `fieldset` border using CSS:

```
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
legend {
    text-align: center;
}
```

For a live example, see [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XzR8k/).

Comment: +1 Much better than my hacky piece of cr*p :). `fieldset` and `legend` is the right way to go, more semantic as well.

Comment: that's what i was looking for, just forgot about fieldset, I'm working with Dashcode at the moment (unfortunately) so it will need some adaptation but anyway, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a simple pure css based solution.

A method that somewhat achieves what you want is to have [text shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/) on the text floating above the border, using a color that blends with the general color of the background. You can tweak the values such that the border will (at least mostly) fade away behind the text. This will of course also fade away the background image, replacing it with the color of the shadow, but it might look fairly nice anyway. (Having a more solid background for the text will make it easier to read, too).